# How to enable queryable snapshots in MongoDB Ops Manager

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-mms

I've found that, there is a way to use queryable backup snapshots in MongoDB ops manager. It is one of their selling points. Although, I cannot find a way to enable/setup these. The only options I see where there should be a "query" option, are "View all snapshots", "Restore" and others – non related ones. Maybe this feature is only available for MongoDB Enterprise builds (the cluster we have runs Community edition 4.0.11)?

Answer (score 1):

This is not very well advertised here:

https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/tutorial/query-backup/

The setup is described in the "prerequisites" section. Basically you click on admin, configuration and the select the backup tab. Scroll down and you will find where you can enter the PEM file.

Comment: It is an enterprise feature, by the way.